# Error conexion base de datos en Hostinger

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, base-de-datos

Que tal colegas tengo un problema al conextar mi base de datos online este es mi codigo:

```
    <?php
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "u309565199_user";
$database = "u309565199_name";
$password = "Google-20";
//  Create a new connection to the MySQL database using PDO
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password);
// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
} 
echo "Connected successfully";
?>
```

Ya se creo la conexion remota, no se en que dato estoy mal, ya se hizo cambios en el server y aun nada. Me sale este error: Connection failed: Access denied for user 'u309565199_user'@'localhost' (using password: YES)

Aqui pueden ver la pagina: http://www.deanddevelopment.com/conexion.php

Comment: ¿Estás pagando por hostinger? La capa gratuita tiene esa restricción.

Comment: Si estoy usando hostinger amigo, tengo comprado un paquete profesional.

Comment: En el `new` no estás pasando el 4º parámetro, que sería la base de datos a la que quieres conectar, algo así: **`$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $database);`** [Revisa la documentacion y los ejemplos](https://www.php.net/manual/es/mysqli.construct.php). Si aún así no funciona, significa que ese usuario realmente no tiene permiso para esa BD o que la contraseña no es la correcta. Otra cosa, si has publicado tu contraseña real en esta pregunta debes cambiarla de inmediato usando una contraseña más complicada y no volver a publicar tu contraseña final.